# How can I update object property using riverpod StateProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm a riverpod newbie.

I think it's a simple code, but it's difficult because it doesn't work.
I really don't know the cause.

The counter value is not updated on the UI even when the FloatingActionButton is clicked.
Counter value on the UI is still 0.

Why? and How can I update it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Counter {
  String title;
  int value;

  Counter(this.title, this.value);
}

final counterProvider = StateProvider<Counter>((ref) {
  return Counter('New Counter', 0);
});

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Counter counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(counter.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('${counter.value}'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider).value++,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `.notifier`. Take a look at [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_provider#how-to-update-the-state-based-on-the-previous-value-without-reading-the-provider-twice)

You can do something like this;

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () => ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).update((state) => state.value + 1),
  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I got found my solution. ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).update((state) => Counter(state.title, state.value + 1))

Comment: @plztrial4me, Please create an answer with the solution you've found and the reason why it didn't work before.

Comment: @plztrial4me so you have to create an entirely new object to update an attribute of an object? Yikes. When using `Provider`, I usually kept all my state in a single class with setter methods triggering `notifyListeners()`. With `Riverpod` I might have to put each attribute in its own individual global Provider or something - sounds messy. But, still learning...